# Share Extension notification with iOS9 multitasking

Tags: ios, ios9, multitasking, splitview, share-extension

I have an app with a Share Extension. Doing some work to fully support iOS9 multitasking and am stuck with a problem: how can the extension tell the main app when something happened?

The original design used an NSUserDefaults object with the app group. When the user switched back to my app I would trap the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification and check the app group.

Now if another app running in the split view with mine calls my Share Extension, there is no notification or appDelegate call to tell me to check. Any thoughts?

Update: I've tried KVO observeValueForKeyPath and NSUserDefaults NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification notification. These do notify the Share Extension of the changes, but they do not trigger a notification in the host app.